# jdbc-hsqldb exception for text table

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

My java code is :

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "password"); // line 1

stm = conn.createStatement(); // line 2

stm.execute("CREATE TEXT TABLE someTableName("NLID" VARCHAR(20),
 "Scheduled.Primary.Scripting.Code" VARCHAR(20), "Scheduled.Site" VARCHAR(20),
 "Scheduled.Location.Long.Name" VARCHAR(20),
 "primary_key_1644" int PRIMARY KEY)"); // line 3

stm.execute("SET TABLE someTableName SOURCE 
"/some.csv;ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true;shutdown=true""); // line 4
```

The CSV which is being linked to the hsqldb is :

```
NLID,Scheduled.Primary.Scripting.Code,Scheduled.Site,Scheduled.Location.Long.Name,primary_key_1644   
100,INMRSB,Shopping,Shopping General-Banner-728x90-INMRSB-I,1 
100002,MSVT08,MSN Video,msnbc.com-TODAYshow.com Special Sponsorships 8-Streaming Media-300x60-MSVT08-S,2  
100004,MSV10T,MSN Video,msnbc.com-TODAYshow.com Special Sponsorships 10-Streaming Media-300x60-MSV10T-S,3
```

I get the below exception in line 4 :

`java.sql.SQLException: bad TEXT table source file - line number: 1196 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S" in statement [SET TABLE someTableName SOURCE "/some.csv;ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true;shutdown=true"]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S"
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TextTable.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TextTable.openCache(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TextTable.setDataSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputText.readInteger(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputBase.readData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputText.readData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputBase.readData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.rowio.RowInputText.readData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.RowAVLDiskData.getRowData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVLDiskData.get(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more`

Any help will be appreciable .

**EDITED :**  Hsqldb throws NumberFormatException while reading a column which is defined as VARCHAR !!!

**MODIFIED :** The exception occurs because one of the column values has a comma in it like `"Mind, Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S"` . Since the hsqldb reads the csv as a table so an additional comma is interpreted as an additional column by the hsql . Can anyone guide me how to circumvent this ?

Comment: It's obvious "Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S" is not a number, so the error.

Comment: The column is defined as VARCHAR(20) .

Comment: Column maybe defined as varchar, but somewhere in your code you are trying to convert it to a number, and you aren't showing us that code :)

Comment: Are you're sure, you're showing us the correct CSV? The string `Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S` is not shown in the CSV, but hsqldb is complaining about it.

Comment: stm.execute("SET TABLE someTableName SOURCE 
"/some.csv;ignore_first=true;all_quoted=true;shutdown=true""); throws the exception . Pls follow the stack trace carefully , the exception is thrown from the jar , not my code .

Comment: @flash : sorry i got the error now , that field "Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S" was in  about 1000 lines from the beginning of the CSV and i just pasted the initial few lines . My mistake . That column value has a comma in it and hence being interpreted by hsql as separate columns .

Comment: Is the value containing the comma quoted? If not: make sure your quote either that value or all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP found out, following these simple steps help find the problem in the CSV file:

1. Look at the error message: `bad TEXT table source file - line number: 1196`  The line number is the line number of the CSV file. Using a text editor, go to that line. Lines are numbered from 1.
2. `ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Body Connection-Banner-728x90-HEAMBA-S"` note NumberFormatException indicates a number was expected, instead the reported string was found.
3. Luckily, there is only one number (INT) column in the table, so it's easy to see there is an extra comma in the CVS, which terminates the last VARCHAR string and causes the problem.
4. The TEXT table definition includes `all_quoted=true`, which means if you use double quotes around the string that contains the comma, the whole string is treated as a field and the problem disappears.